# Electron app not showing anything

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I make a simple "hello world" type Electron app. After double click the exe file it not open any window at all. Just a thread showing in windows tasks manager. I try to debug main thread js. But it show no error. And if I run development mode it works(cli: electron main.js).

ENV: windows 7, x64

Build command: electron-builder

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I find the problem is package.json `main` property. The `main` property should point to main.js (main thread entry js file).